# Pause Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder programmatically

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I work on Spring Boot application, which uses Spring Cloud Stream for integration with Kafka.

I need to pause receiving messages from Kafka programmatically. I khow about possibility to manage lifecycle of bindings by actuator endpoint ([docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_visualization_and_control)).
So i can autowire `org.springframework.cloud.stream.endpoint.BindingsEndpoint` and use it's public methods. But it seems to me little strange...

Is there better way to manage lifecycle of bindings programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's OK to use that `BindingsEndpoint` bean in your own code. It's purpose is really to manage a lifecycle for the bindings. There is just a simple bonus with that bean that it is exposed as an actuator endpoint to manage bindings over REST.

Otherwise you would go the way to copy/paste the logic of the `BindingsEndpoint`...

Comment: Artem, thanks, but there is one more question
I found the `InputBindingLifecycle` and `OutputBindingLifecycle` beans. They have "start" and "stop" methods, which can do almost the same as BindingsEndpoint (for my requirements fits both ways)
Which way preferable?

Comment: You may have several bindings in your application, so, a single management place is much preferable, than the way to try to find an appropriate `Bindable` via `AbstractBindingLifecycle`. Although if that is OK for your just to stop/start them all at the same time, you are good to go with what you have figured out for yourself.